# Group rows in a dataframe, take the max values and compute the groups mean

Tags: r, dataframe, rows, lubridate

I have got the following dataframe:

```
df <- read.table(text = "
    Station    Area  Day       Flow
1     21009 4390.00  1913   725.661
2     24005  178.50  1913    25.540
3     25009 1264.00  1913   318.481
4     27002  758.90  1913   230.556
5     38003  133.90  1913     2.823
70    37006  228.40  9526    68.140
71    37008  190.30  9526    38.175
72    37009   60.70  9526    12.200
73    37018   47.90  9526    19.209
156   38021   42.20  12551    15.330
157   39093  117.60  12551    33.090
158   40004  206.00  12551    49.019
159   41005  180.90  12551    63.574
188   41006   87.80  14329    67.130
189   41011  154.00  14329   125.000
190   41012   93.30  14329    43.640
191   41014  379.00  14329   218.000
192   41015   58.30  14329     5.080", header = TRUE)
```

I would like to apply the `dplyr` package (should be the quickest way) in order to group the rows by the column `Day`, then take the max and the mean value of `Area`, while keeping the corresponding observations in the other 2 columns.

My output should be:

```
    Station    Area  Day        Flow  Group_mean
1     21009 4390.00  1913    725.661    1345.06
70    37006  228.40  9526     68.140     131.83 
158   40004  206.00  12551    49.019     136.68
191   41014  379.00  14329   218.000     154.48
```

Comment: What is the logic for getting the `Station` in the expected output

Comment: hi @akrun and thanks. there is no logic for the stations as they will be selected automatically with the max Area for each group.

Comment: I just found that you deleted a question that you posted.  I spend some time to answer it...

Comment: yes, I removed it because unfortunately the code didn't work with my real dataframe. I am sorry. By the way..now my stack overflow account has been blocked if this makes you feel better..

Comment: Ok, that is bad for you.  Hopefully, the block will be lifted soon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `dplyr`.  After grouping by 'Day', we `summarise` the data by taking the `first` value of 'Area', value of 'Station', where the 'Flow' is maximum, get the `max` 'Flow' and also the `mean` of 'Area'.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(Day) %>%
   summarise(Area1 = max(Area), 
             Station = Station[which.max(Flow)], 
             Flow = max(Flow), 
             Group_mean = mean(Area)) %>%
             rename(Area = Area1)
#     Day   Area Station    Flow Group_mean
#   <int>  <dbl>   <int>   <dbl>      <dbl>
#1  1913 4390.0   21009 725.661   1345.060
#2  9526  228.4   37006  68.140    131.825
#3 12551  206.0    41005  63.574    136.675
#4 14329  379.0    41014 218.000    154.480
```

EDIT: Based on @agenis and @Sotos comments

Comment: I think you need to compute the mean first and then take the max (otherwise it makes no sense to take the mean of max value) but yes, OP needs to clarify better

Comment: @Sotos  Thanks for the hint, I forgot that I changed the variable.

Comment: please forget about the flow column, I am only interested in the max Area and Area mean for each group of rows, grouped by Day.

Comment: you're welcome! did I deserve 5 points for this ? ;-)  (by the way I saw your profile with so many answers how come you never asked a single question yourself?)

Comment: @agenis Most of the questions that I had were already getting answered :-)

Answer (score 3):

You could use sqldf by

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf("select Station, max(Area), Day, Flow, sum(Area)/count(*) as mean from df group by Day")
```